# Top navigation does not work when I add a dropdown link

Tags: navigation, submenu

When I added a submenu (ex. Our Team) to the top navigation (ex. About), the top navigation link does not work. When I tried to mouseover the About link, I noticed the URL path was not pointing to the page. It only shows http://www.dominionent.org/#

I tried to look at the css but was unable to determine what needed to be modified.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is a bit lacking in detail at the moment. If you can provide a little more info - ideally with an example of the code you're having trouble with - it'll be easier for people to help.

Comment: Below is the css for my Wordpress site navigation. Currently, the "About" link does not link to the "About" page whenever I add a submenu. I need to fix the top navigation so that the submenu and the top navigation active links work.

Comment: /*  Navigation
-----------------------------------------------------------  */
.nav-wrapper {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF9311;position: relative;}
.nav-wrapper:before {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #76037c;position: absolute;content: '';width: 50%;height: 100%;top: 0;right: 0;z-index: 298;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper .slogan {text-align: center;color: #FFFFFF;background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF9311;}
.nav-wrapper .slogan h3 {color: #FFFFFF;line-height: 50px;margin-bottom: 0 !important;font-size: 18px;}
.nav-wrapper .navbar-collapse {border: medium none;}
.nav-wrapper .navbar-default {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #76037c;border-radius: 0 0 0 0;box-shadow: none;border: medium none;margin: 0 0 0 0;z-index: 300;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {border: medium none;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 34px;padding: 0 10px;border-radius: 0 0 0 0;}
.nav-wrapper .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.nav-wrapper .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {background-color: transparent;background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}

Comment: .nav-wrapper ul.nav-main i {color: #FF9311;font-size: 13px;}
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > li {font-size: 11px;font-weight: bold;padding: 0 22px 0;}
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > li:first-child {padding: 0 22px 0 14px;}
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > li:last-child {padding: 0 0 0 22px;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > li a {padding: 0 0 0;background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;border-radius: 0 0 0;color: #FFFFFF;line-height: 50px;box-shadow: none;text-shadow: none;text-transform: uppercase;-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > li a:hover,
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > li a:focus {color: #FFFFFF;}
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > .active > a,
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > .active > a:hover,
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > .active > a:focus {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;color: #FFFFFF;}
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > .open > a,
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > .open > a:hover,
.nav-wrapper ul.nav-main > .open > a:focus {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;color: #FFFFFF;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {display: block;}
.nav-wrapper li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF9311;border-radius: 0 0 0;border: medium none;margin: 0 0 0;padding: 0 0 0;}
.nav-wrapper li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li {font-size: 11px;padding: 0 14px 0;border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .12);-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:first-child {border-top: medium none !important;}
.nav-wrapper li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:last-child {border-bottom: medium none !important;}
.nav-wrapper li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li a {color: #76037c;line-height: 38px;}
.nav-wrapper li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:hover {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #221918;}
.nav-wrapper li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li a {color: #FFFFFF;background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:hover a {color: #FFFFFF;}
.nav-wrapper li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:hover a:hover {color: #FFFFFF;background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}

.nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown {position: relative;}
.nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown:after {position: absolute;content: "\f105";right: 14px;top: 0;color: #221918;font: 13px 'FontAwesome';line-height: 38px;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown:hover:after {color: #FF9311;}
.nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF9311;display: none;position: absolute;left: 100%;top: 100%;margin: -38px 0 0 0;width: 100% !important;padding: 0 0 0;border-radius: 0 0 0;border: medium none;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {display: block;}
.nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li {font-size: 11px;padding: 0 14px 0;border-bottom: 1px solid #e77e00;border-top: 1px solid #ffa436;-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:first-child {border-top: medium none !important;}
.nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:last-child {border-bottom: medium none !important;}
.nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:hover {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #221918;}
.nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li a {color: #FFFFFF !important;line-height: 38px !important;}
.nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:hover a {color: #FFFFFF !important;}

Comment: .nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:hover a {color: #FFFFFF !important;}
.nav-wrapper li.nested-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu > li:hover a:hover {color: #FFFFFF !important;}

Comment: Hey, why not just edit the question? The CSS as you've posted it in comments is unreadable. This is really not what comments are for.